# How to print WPF layout to not be dependent on the screen resolution?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I've been trying to use the following method to print a page on A4 paper. If my application runs on a laptop where the resolution is 1366x768 the printout scales down and I have no idea why? If I run it on a PC where the monitor resolution is higher, it prints as it should. I have tried to change `PageMediaSize`, `ScaleTransform`, `LayoutTransform`, `Windows.Size` with no success. What am I doing wrong?

The first 4 lines are there because I am sometimes using a 'print preview' where I'm scaling the page using a Viewbox, so the user can resize the preview. To not to affect the printing I am setting the Height and Width right before printing but outside of the PC's visible desktop area so it is not visible for the user.

```
var desktopWorkingArea = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
this.Top = desktopWorkingArea.Bottom + 100;
this.Height = 1250;
this.Width = 815;
System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog printDlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
printDlg.PrintQueue = new System.Printing.PrintQueue(new System.Printing.PrintServer(), printerName);

System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities = printDlg.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDlg.PrintTicket);

//get scale of the print wrt to screen of WPF visual
double scale = Math.Min(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / this.ActualWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight / this.ActualHeight);

//Transform the Visual to scale
this.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

//get the size of the printer page
System.Windows.Size sz = new System.Windows.Size(this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight); //(8.5 * 96.0, 11.0 * 96.0);

//update the layout of the visual to the printer page size.
this.Measure(sz);
this.Arrange(new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), sz));

//now print the visual to printer to fit on the one page.
printDlg.PrintVisual(this, "Certificate - " + serialNumberTextBlock.Text);
```